# Does TFVC in Azure DevOps automatically write the check-in comment to the discussion for a work item?

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc

I have been tasked with figuring out to solve this issue. I am working on a project that uses TFVC in Azure Devops and when a check-in is made the system adds that comment to the discussion thread on the work item. What setting can I change to turn that off?

**UPDATED**:

I created a test TFVC project in a separate DevOps account that I had with no extensions installed. Checked in changes, a link was added to the Development sections as expected but just like described above it was also added to the discussion, see screenshot. So this appears to be default behavior so how do we turn it off?

[image]

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT I updated my questions with the latest info.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot turn this feature off once you have linked the checkin with the work item.

Answer (score 0):

> Does TFVC in Azure DevOps automatically write the check-in comment to
>   the discussion for a work item?

For this issue, the answer is no. The comment added in Check in will be used as the title of the changeset(TFVC) and will not be automatically written to the discussion of the work item.

[image][image]

Changesets will be linked to the Development field of the work item to drive development.

[image]

Comment: they are being linked in the development section as expected but also added to the discussion thread, I am trying to keep them from being added to the discussion thread to reduce clutter. thanks.

Comment: As Leo said, it is not copied to discussion by default, you need to check your extension to see if this caused this situation.

Comment: see my comments to Leo, It does appear that they are copied by default.

Answer (score 0):

> Does TFVC in Azure DevOps automatically write the check-in comment to the discussion for a work item?

Obviously not.

Automatically write check-in comments to the discussion of work items is not applicable to all users, so MS does not add it as the default behavior.

And as test, I could not found this issue on my side, and you could also to check this issue on the other organization or new organization.

As a bold guess, your organization may have one extension installed and these behaviors are performed by this extension, like [Work Item Autosave](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=seanferguson.vsts-extension-wit-autosave#:~:targetText=Work%20Item%20Autosave,before%20the%20save%20is%20attempted.). But I could not sure it, you need to check your extensions one by one, `Organization Settings`->`Extensions`.

If you find that extension, you can disable or change the settings to disable this feature.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the insight i will check into extensions.

Comment: I have not been able to track down the extension yet that is causing it. What's weird is it's only on the TFVC back repositories not on the GIT backed repositories. I am still digging into it.

Comment: I tested this with a new TFVC project in a separate DevOps that had no extensions and the checkin notes were added to the discussion of the work item so it does appear to be the default. I would love to figure out how to turn that off as it adds noise to the discussion thread.

Comment: @tanzencoder, That's weird. Would you please update your question with some screenshots about this issue, maybe i understand it wrong.